# LabVIEW: How to check if a reference has been close or not?

Tags: .net, null, labview

I am trying to figure out how to find if a object I created on LabVIEW whose reference has been closed or not.

I have such a diagram as below what I am trying to do is as follows:
[image: close camera event structure]
This is **Close Camera** event case:

1. check if Library is initialized or not
2. if yes then check if Camera is open
3. if yes then Close Camera and close the reference.

This logic fails if this event is called twice.
After calling once the Camera reference is closed but at the 2nd attempt 
Camera::IsOpen is called. At this time Camera instance is not referenced.
Then it will throw an exception.

Before calling Camera::IsOpen I would like to check the Camera object to make sure it is not **NULL**.

Is there a way to check it ?

Note that Library is a static function so it doesn't have to be instantiated but Camera has to instantiated to invoke its methods and properties.

Thanks

Comment: When you say *it will throw an exception*, do you have automatic error handling enabled for the VI? If so then turn it off, and add code to check the error output from the `IsOpen` node to check for the specific error. In general once you're past the absolute beginner stage with LabVIEW you don't want the automatic error handling.

Answer (score 4):

**To check for the refnum having never been opened in the first place, you can compare for equality against the Not A Refnum constant.** There is a different refnum constant for different data types. To create any Not A Refnum constant for your particular data type, right click on the wire and select Create >> Constant. The newly created constant always has a value of Not A Refnum. The "Not A Refnum" constant that is in the palettes is seriously a misnomer and should probably be removed from the palettes since it cannot represent all data types. 
[image]

**To check whether a refnum that you once opened has been closed or not, just call a function on that refnum. If it returns an error, check if the error is error code 1. If it is, then the refnum is invalid.**

Seriously, the above is the best way to check if a refnum has been closed. You could, in theory, use the Not A Number/Refnum/Path function, but this generally leads to race conditions! I've seen many programs make this mistake: "Oh, I'll check if the refnum is valid, then, if it is valid, I'll proceed to take an action that depends upon that refnum, and I won't bother checking for errors because I already know that the reference is valid!" The problem is that right after you check whether the refnum is valid, and before you get around to doing your operation, another parallel thread could close the reference! And then you're hosed. The problem is really bad because that race condition is a really small window, so it usually only replicates on really expensive hardware already deployed into the field on very expensive projects. ;-)

Given the above, the "Not A Number/Refnum/Path" function should generally only be used with refnums as a status INDICATOR. In other words, you can use it for debugging and for display purposes, but don't get in the habit of letting code make decisions based on its results.

[image] << USE WITH CAUTION.

So in your case, just call Close unconditionally -- don't check whether the Camera was open or not... just call close. If you don't get an error, then it was open.

Comment: Could you comment why using "Not a Refnum" could lead to race conditions and why checking for an error does not have this problem? In principle I would expect both methods to be susceptible to race conditions?

Comment: @DJKlomp A member of LabVIEW R&D wrote it up a few years ago here, with further commentary from the community: https://lavag.org/topic/15546-are-you-misusing-the-not-a-refnum-function-and-putting-your-app-at-risk/

Answer (score -1):

Compare it with a [`Not a Refnum`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/glang/not_a_refnum_constant/) [image: not a refnum icon] constant.

If the .NET library doesn't invalidate its reference when you invoke `Close`, then set that wire's value to **Not a Refnum** afterward.

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect. Comparing a refnum value for equality with Not A Refnum does not check whether the refnum has been closed or not. Only a non-zero refnum would ever have been opened in the first place. This answer only answers for the comparison against Not A Refnum, which is only part of the questioner's problem. Also, there's more than one Not A Refnum constant, for different refnum data types. (In LabVIEW, NULLs are typed entities.)

Comment: And what does it even mean to set a wire's value to Not A Refnum? "Close Reference" doesn't have a refnum out.